# inequality derived from law of total variance

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, variance

From the law of total variance we know:
$$
Var(\theta) = E(Var(\theta|Y)) + Var(E(\theta|Y))
$$
Thus we can have
$$
Var(\theta) \geq E(Var(\theta|Y)).
$$
However, how could we prove the following:
$$
Var(\theta|Y>1) \geq E(Var(\theta|Y)|Y>1).
$$
It seems intuitive but I am not confident about that. Also, I don't think
$$
E(X)=E(Y) \quad=>\quad E(X|Z)=E(Y|Z).
$$

Comment: The main concept is that conditional distribution is still a probability distribution. The inequality you have in the second line holds for any pairs of random variable $\theta, Y$ (whenever their second moments exist), so it also holds for another pair. The last implication does not hold of course, and I guess you can easily construct a counter example on your own, but that does not contradict to the results above.

Comment: To complement @BGM's comment, it is important that the condition $\{Y>1\}$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable. This implies that, denoting $\widetilde P$ the conditional probability given $Y>1$, $\widetilde{\operatorname{Var}}(\theta\,|\,Y) = \operatorname{Var}(\theta\,|\,Y)$ on $\{Y>1\}$.